# Не работает flush();

Tags: php

Использую SEE и наткнулся на такой косяк:

На локальном сервере все работает:

```
   public function actionUpdateProposals()
    {
    // id игры 
    $game_id = (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;

    set_time_limit(120);

    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $start = time();

    $lastEventId = floatval(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"] : 0);
    if ($lastEventId == 0) 
    {
        $lastEventId = (isset($_GET["key"])) ? (string)$_GET["key"] : 0;
    }

    while(true) 
    {
        //if ((time() - $start) > 10) {break;}

        //echo ":" . str_repeat(" ", 2048) . "\n"; // 2 kB padding for IE
        echo "retry: 2000\n";
        echo "id: {$lastEventId}" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "data: " . GameOperations::load()->getJsonProposalsData($game_id) . PHP_EOL;
        echo PHP_EOL;

        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

}
```

Что должно быть:
Соединяемся держим соединение 2 минуты, в это время каждые 5 секунд отдаем данные. 
На локалке все хорошо (апатч)

Переносим на сервер (нгинкс) и выхватываем:
Ждет 2 минуты, конектиться отдает данные теряет соединение. Ждет 2 минуты и так далее...

Прочитал про всякие настройки типа:

```
output_buffering = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

Поставил, теперь выглядит вот так:
Соединение 
Обновление данных 
Потеря соединения 
Соединение 
Обновление данных 
Потеря соединения 
Соединение 
Обновление данных 
Потеря соединения

И так бомбит постоянно.

на нгинксе добавил:

```
gzip off;
proxy_buffering off;
```

Всеравно не спасло.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo str_pad('',1024);
@ob_flush();
flush();
```

Да, на Денвере работает. А, например, в windows server 2012 стоит IIS8 и размер буфера по умолчанию 4МБ. Его, конечно, можно заполнить подобным образом через echo str_pad(' ', 4294967296); , но в этом случае вывод текста происходит только первый раз, а всё остальное только в конце скрипта. Причём даже если поставить str_pad  в цикл. Да и гонять постоянно 4МБ тоже нагрузка.
В настройках IIS8 буферизация вывода так запросто не отключается. Буферизацию в IIS8 можно выключить или уменьшить, если поправить файл
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xls.
Но у админа нет прав на его запись, и даже при остановленном IIS система показывает access denied. И в свойствах файла права не устанавливаются.
Доступ можно открыть, выполнив следующий батник

```
SET DIRECTORY_NAME="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema"
TAKEOWN /f %DIRECTORY_NAME% /r /d y
ICACLS %DIRECTORY_NAME% /grant administrators:F /t
PAUSE
```

В самом файле IIS_schema.xls значение «bufferingOn» ставим false. Значения «bufferingLimit», «responseBufferLimit», «receiveBufferLimit» по умолчанию установлены 4194304. Меняем на 4096. Если ещё меньше, то IIS не запускается, тип Integer у него предполагает значение от 4096, о чём он и сообщает при попытке запуска.

После этих исправлений в файле IIS_schema.xls, наконец, пошёл динамический вывод текста на php 5.6 на IIS8. Этим самым способом, когда один раз выполняем

```
echo str_pad('', 1024);
@ob_flush();
flush();
```

А потом просто flush();

Answer (score 1):

У меня вот так заработало

```
<?php
echo str_pad('',1024);
@ob_flush();
flush();
```

Это для первого вывода. А дальше где надо уже просто
flush();